# ASP .NET Web API 2 + angularJS go to login page after token expired

Tags: c#, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I've developed AngularJS SPA, backend is ASP .NET Web API, OWIN auth. The main issue is when OWIN token expires I want immediately redirect user to login page. What is the best way to achive my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: Examine the status code of each request if it is 401 that means the user is not authorized, then you should redirect him to login page

Comment: thanks for response, but it's not what I'm trying to achive: if the user typing in some data, then save it, but if his token expired he will be redirected to login page and he will loose all entered data. It's not user friendly at all... 
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: but you need to check not not only on post request but also when he request a page so before fill any data in form

Comment: you're right, but what if when he started filling the data token wasn't expired (for ex. he started to fill the form yeasterday, then continued to fill the next day), posted the data, but the token is already expired? I think, it will be better to redirect him to the login page right after token expired, isn't it?